# Changing dateformat enters wrong date in database

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I am working on a MVC application in which I am adding date and editing date using datepicker(jquery).

In want dateformat for user as dd/mm/yyyy but when I set dateformat like this; in database it goes like 01/01/0001. On debug I found that Null value is being passed to controller.

My code in Model Class :

`[Display(Name = "Deadline")]
 [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
 public DateTime Deadline { get; set; }`

In View :

`<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#Deadline").datepicker
            ({
                dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
            });
        });
</script>`

`<%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Deadline) %>`

Comment: It isn't that the wrong date is being saved, it's that the date isn't being passed across to the server side code so it's saving the default value for `DateTime`

Comment: ya date is not being passed. So what can I do solve the problem.

Comment: How is the model being passed to the controller? Standard HTTP Post? Ajax?

Comment: Try passing `FormCollection` as a parameter into your controller action - is there a `Deadline` key value pair in there with the correct value? Trying to ascertain whether it's model binding that's the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try adding this to ur web.config file with the country globalization value ...**

```
<system.web>
    <globalization culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB" />
  </system.web>
```

**and also this on the view side ...**

```
$("#Deadline").datepicker({
                showOn: "both",
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                changeMonth: true,
            });
```

**i got similar problem before but on db side i used string as datatype to store ..**
let me know if it works

Comment: Its showing date with time `13/02/2013 00:00:00` also datepicker stopped working. also I dont want time with date.

Comment: Solved all... Thank you for help. needed to add `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime Deadline { get; set; }` and all worked fine

Answer (score 0):

I got solution for the problem like

In Web Config :

```
<system.web>
    <globalization culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB" />
  </system.web>
```

In Modlel Class :

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime Deadline { get; set; }
```

In View :

```
        $(function () {
            $("#Deadline").datepicker
            ({
                dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
            });
        });
```